# Windows 2012 VPN setup without Active Directory

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server-2012, dialup

I have followed the guide here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qbpxKRb-94

But my situation differs with respect to there being no AD (Active Directory) setup.

When I try to connect I get this in the server event log:
"The user xx connected from x.x.x.x but failed an authentication attempt due to the following reason: The account does not have permission to dial in."

Is there a way to enable this without AD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use compmgmt.msc.  Select System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Users.  Right-click the account properties, and select the DialIn tab.